# LocalizationProvider localization crashes with an error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, localization, calendar

I use

"material-react-table": "^1.6.5" | "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4" | "@mui/material": "^5.11.7" | "@mui/styles": "^5.11.7" | "@mui/x-date-pickers" : "^5.0.18" | "@material-ui/pickers" : "3.0.0"

I'm taking an example

https://material-ui-docs.netlify.app/x/react-date-pickers/localization/

but

```js
Filter: ({ column }) => (
  <LocalizationProvider
    adapterLocale="ru"
    localeText={ruRU.components.MuiLocalizationProvider.defaultProps.localeText}
    dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}
  >
    <DatePicker
      onChange={(newValue) => {
        column.setFilterValue(newValue);
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          helperText={"Filter Mode: Lesss Than"}
          sx={{ minWidth: "120px" }}
          variant="standard"
        />
      )}
      value={column.getFilterValue()}
    />
  </LocalizationProvider>
);
```

localization crashes with an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'L')
    at index.js:36:1
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at AdapterDayjs.expandFormat (index.js:34:1)
    at AdapterDayjs.getFormatHelperText (index.js:41:1)
    at useMaskedInput (useMaskedInput.js:23:1)
    at KeyboardDateInput (KeyboardDateInput.js:29:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:19226:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21636:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
```

changed the version of dependencies, used CalendarPicker, "date-fns/locale/ru"

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this working by adding the UTC plugin:

```
dayjs.extend(utc);
(dayjs.utc as any).Ls = dayjs.Ls;

const Filter: ({ column }) => (
  <LocalizationProvider
    adapterLocale="ru"
    localeText={ruRU.components.MuiLocalizationProvider.defaultProps.localeText}
    dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}
    dateLibInstance={dayjs.utc}
  >
```